# Avoid annotation @Where clause in model (Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I have in my model:

```
@Entity
@Where(clause="is_deleted <> '1'")
public class Ad {
```

In 95% i will work with not deleted ads. But for one method I need to get all deleted ads. How I can avoid this `Where` clause in query? i'm using `CriteriaBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally add another api in the DAO class for the entity to find all the deleted ads,Also followin the priciple of separation of concerns,there should not be any logic in the pojo/entity class.

Comment: Downvoting for the last sentence as it leads to anemic model